# Migrate question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration, software-engineering-se

Shouldn't this question have been moved to the Programmers SE instead of being deleted?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144/how-can-i-convince-skeptical-management-and-colleagues-to-allow-refactoring-of-a

Comment: If a question is old (>60 days), it can't be migrated.

Answer (score 4):

Questions older than 60 days can not be migrated to other sites.

However, my personal recommendation would be for an SO mod to [historical lock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/historical-lock/info) that question rather than delete. I'm not sure when historical lock was started, though, but it may have been after that question was deleted. Although it is off-topic, it seems to contain some useful answers, along with some that are pure opinion and not grounded in facts or supported by references.

Comment: I don't really see that question as *so* valuable it needs a historical lock.  Historical locks are designed for the really, really, really valuable content, with lots and lots of external links coming in.  This question has 1.5k views, which really isn't a lot compared to questions that get a historical lock, and doesn't indicate much in the way of externally linked content.

Comment: @Servy Externally linked content has nothing to do with it. If migration was possible, I'd suggest that it be migrated to Programmers. However, it's not possible, yet the question does appear to add value to the network. Deletion doesn't seem like the best option here.

Comment: Historical locks aren't for content with some value.  They're designed for content with *overwhelming value*, to which having the content deleted would be a *significant* loss.  That's just not the case here.  The content just isn't *that* valuable.  Having lots of views, and lots of incoming external references contributes to a posts' value.  That this post doesn't have much of either means less is lost from it being deleted.  Historical locks also exist for controversial content that is constantly being deleted/undeleted/opened/closed, which this isn't.

Comment: @Servy As a moderator on Programmers, that is a valuable question that could serve as a valuable reference. It's also a pretty important question. If it was possible, I'd ask for it to be migrated. However, that's not possible. Right now, the question meets 2 of the 4 criteria for a historical lock. If it's undeleted, it meets 3 of the 4.

Comment: It is offtopic, that's a yes for #1.  It's not *stellar*.  It's pretty good, but not *stellar*, so that's a no for #2.  It doesn't have a large number of views, upvotes, or inbound links, so that's a no for three.  The post is not contentious.  That's 1 for 4.  Even if you asserted it was *stellar*, which I disagree with, you're still way off from all 4.

Comment: @Servy You don't need all four. 2 or even 3 is sufficient for a historical lock. And it's clearly contentious since we're having this discussion (and I voted to un-delete the question).

Comment: So far you're the *only* person to have voted to delete or reopen the question.  One dissenting person doesn't make it contentious in my eyes.  I would also assert that it takes all 4 criteria for a historical lock to be applied.  If any one of them doesn't apply, then the lock shouldn't be used.  In any case, this post doesn't meet 2 or 3 criteria; it meets 1, along with the many many thousands of other closed posts that are offtopic or not constructive.  If you want to re-ask it on Programmers, where it may be on topic, that would be fine.